# Are host configurations in the SSH config merged?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, openssh

I have the following generic host configuration in my `.ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host *
  ConnectTimeout 5
  ServerAliveInterval 5
  ServerAliveCountMax 12
```

I also have some specific configurations. For example the following alias:

```
Host work-server-1
  Hostname a.b.c.d

Host work-server-2
  Hostname i.j.k.l
```

Now, my question: when logging into the host `work-server-1`, will SSH also use the `ConnectTimeout`, `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` setting as defined in the `Host *` entry?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For each directive, the **first relevant occurrence in the `ssh_config` is used**.

Quoting [man page for `ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config):

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used. The configuration files contain sections separated by `Host` specifications, and that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns given in the specification. ...
>
> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

---

So with the configuration file below:

- For all hosts, `ServerAliveInterval 1` is always used, `4` and `7` are never used, not even for `work`.
- `ConnectTimeout` is `2` for `work`, for other hosts it's `3`.
- For all hosts, the `ServerAliveCountMax` is `5`, the `work`-specific value `6` is never used, not even for `work`.

```
ServerAliveInterval 1

Host work
  ConnectTimeout 2

Host *
  ConnectTimeout 3
  ServerAliveInterval 4
  ServerAliveCountMax 5

Host work
  ServerAliveCountMax 6
  ServerAliveInterval 7
```

Comment: Much obliged Martin.

Comment: You can even use the ssh verbosity flags to see which sets of configurations in which files were loaded, to debug issues

Comment: Martin, Martin, he's the man, if he can't do it, then no one can!!