# MacOS SSH client always wants to connect to same server

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, terminal

I have set up a new virtual server today, including PubKeyAuthentication and so on...

If I now want to connect to other servers via SSH the client always wants to connect to one I was mainly working with today - regardless the addresses and also regardless the terminal app that I'm using (I have tried Terminal and Tabby).

It kinda looks like this:

```
ssh root@192.168.178.34
```

the answer is

```
root@xxxxxxxx.stratoserver.net: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Also if I try to connect to another server on Strato:

```
root@yyyyyyyyy.stratoserver.net
```

the answer is always

```
root@xxxxxxxx.stratoserver.net: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Connecting to

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -l user xxxxxxxx.stratoserver.net
```

works fine.

As mentioned it is regardless of the terminal app. I have also restarted my machine without any change.

The content of the `~/.ssh/config` is

```
User username
HostName xxxxxxxx.stratoserver.net
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host connectionname_x (username)
        User username
        HostName xxxxxxx.stratoserver.net
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host connectionname_y (root)
        User root
        HostName yyyyyyyy.stratoserver.net

Host connectionname_local
        User root
        HostName 192.168.178.34
```

Comment: I have deleted the ~/.ssh/config and started from scratch. Now everything works nicely. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are host configurations in the SSH config merged?](https://superuser.com/questions/1456255/are-host-configurations-in-the-ssh-config-merged)